# Draw a line in C#, but only return coordinates

Tags: c#, .net

I need a small C# function, which performs Bresenhams Line Drawing, but all it would do is create an array (or list) of integer, and store all X/Y coordinates there.

It would:

1. Take X Start, X End, Y Start, Y End integers, which represent start/end coordinates
2. Internally perform line drawing
3. Return X/Y coordinates of all pixels in a list.

Thanks.

Comment: "And actually, Console does not matter here" you're right, you're just looking for a standard C# method. The type of application (Console, WPF, etc) doesn't matter. This sounds like some simple math to determine the output you're after. What have you tried so far?

Comment: How would you draw a line from 1/2 to 2/2? How many points are that and which? Ands from 1/1 to 6/2?

Comment: @gunr2171 while I agree with your comment, I would not say it is "simple math" - since line drawing has algorithms named after people it somewhat indicates that there are tricky areas there (would be rude to suggest if OP did not read those)... Just for fun consider reading [how to draw circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm) for an example of how non-simple simple math of drawing could be. If we also consider more modern properly anti-aliased line an algorithm even for straight line becomes far more interesting.

Comment: It would be much clearer if you just asked for _what are all the (x,y) coordinates of all the "pixels" that need to be drawn to render a line between two given end-points_.

Comment: See [this function](https://github.com/ja72/ConsoleDraw/blob/0de529ff793e07b0885abe5fdcaf8429ef39563b/CRender.cs#L62) that draws a line in a `Console` window by subdividing the line into `n` pixels and drawing a dot (or square) on each pixel.

Comment: @nvoigt I am not drawing from X1 Y1 to X2 Y2, these are variables that indicate: X1 - From (X), Y1 - From (Y), X2 - To (X), Y2 - To (Y)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function takes four arguments: the x and y coordinates of the starting point, and the x and y coordinates of the ending point. It returns a list of coordinates, where each one represents the x and y coordinates of a pixel on the line. Basically this [algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm)

```
public static List<(int, int)> GetLineCoordinates(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
{
    List<(int, int)> coordinates = new List<(int, int)>();
    
    int dx = Math.Abs(x2 - x1);
    int dy = Math.Abs(y2 - y1);
    int sx = x1 < x2 ? 1 : -1;
    int sy = y1 < y2 ? 1 : -1;
    int err = dx - dy;
    int x = x1;
    int y = y1;
    
    while (true) {
        coordinates.Add((x, y));
        
        if (x == x2 && y == y2) {
            break;
        }
        
        int e2 = 2 * err;
        
        if (e2 > -dy) {
            err -= dy;
            x += sx;
        }
        
        if (e2 < dx) {
            err += dx;
            y += sy;
        }
    }
    
    return coordinates;
}
```

Comment: Bresenhams line drawing algorithm as well, perfect. Just what I was looking for. Thanks.